# What is the correct birth story of Chakshush Manu of the 6th Manvantar?

Tags: puranas, manu, harivamsa, manvantara, markandeya-purana

According to the [Markandeya Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/markandeya_purana/chakshush_manvantar.html) Chakshush, the Manu for the previous Manvantar was born to Anmitra and Giribhadra.

> Chakshush had manifested from the eye (Chakshu) of Lord Brahma in his previous birth. For this reason, he was known as Chakshush. Chakshush was born to Anmitra and Giribhadra. After taking birth, he was abducted by Jatharini and exchanged with the son of King Vikrant who was sleeping besides his mother.

However, the [Harivamsa](https://archive.org/stream/TheMahabharata_201707/TheMahabharata_djvu.txt) states that he was born in the lineage of Dhruva:

> Dhruva’s wife, Shambhu, gave birth to sons named Shlishti and Manya. Shlishti’s wife, Succhaya, gave birth to five unblemished sons — Ripu, Ripunjaya, Vipra, Vrikala and Vrikatejasa. Ripu’s wife, Brihati, gave birth to Chakshusha and he possessed every kind of energy. Through Pushkarini, Virana’s daughter, Chakshusha had a son named Chakshusha Manu. This great-souled Prajapati was thus descended from Virana’s lineage.

I have found a third story from the [Devi Bhagwat Puran](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57373.html) which states:

> O Nārada! I will now narrate the supreme glories of the Devī and the anecdote how Manu, the son of Anga, obtained excellent kingdom by worshipping the Devī Bhagavatī. The son of the king Anga, named Cākṣuṣa became the Sixth Manu.

**Which of these stories regarding the origin of the 6th Manu is actually correct?**

Please refrain from the Kalpa Bheda logic I am looking for at least one of the references getting some mention in a different scripture than the ones quoted.

Comment: Many of these lineages confuse themselves within the Puranas. It's likely that one of the answers to this question will cite Kalpa Bheda.

Comment: Haha yes but still I would be happy if at least one of these stories finds some more corroboration.

Comment: The main page is totally filled with the tag edits made. Can you do it slowly with intervals? Also create the tag properly. it is [tag:markandeya-purana].

Comment: First one is correct. Because the word Chakshush means eyes.

Comment: See, from reading earlier, there is one conclusion that can be formed at least about the lineage except Vaivasvata. All the Manus till Chakshusha have been born in the line of Prajapati Swayambhuva Manu. It’s like how son inherits kingdom from father, here the title of Prajapati is inherited many generations down or between brothers or whatever. There are 2 more scriptures which will corroborate this.

Comment: Yes I agree and the ones from the 9th to the 14th are mentioned to be the re-births of the sons of Vaivasvat Manu. I guess only the 6th to 8th are exceptions to the idea of belonging to a lineage.

Comment: If I remember correctly, even 6 has been shown as belonging to a lineage

Comment: 6th is Chakshush for whom the above question was asked so clearly not from a lineage..

Comment: I mean, Chakshusha belonging to lineage is corroborated by 2 more Puranas than what has been quoted in the question. One is brahmanda purana and the other is Bhagavatam, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Can you share the links to those origin stories? If that is the case Chakshush would probably have the most diverse births amongst all other Manus :)

Comment: Brahmanda Purana [verse 102](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana/d/doc362854.html); Bhagavatam [4.13.16](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/4/13/15-16/) in both, he is above Anga in lineage yet part of Swayambhuva’s lineage. It makes sense because Anga’s grandson Prithu was the one who milked the earth in the Vaivasvata Manvanatara. Chakshusha could not have been born after the Vaivasvata started. These two scriptures corroborate the Harivamsa reference as asked in the question. Devi Purana is close except places Anga above Chakshusha. Brahmaji story looks wrong.